# $X,Y$ are independent exponentially distributed then what is the distribution of $X/(1+Y)$

Tags: probability-distributions

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and exponentially distributed, which is the pdf of $Z$?
Where $Z$ is given by
\begin{equation}
Z = \frac{X}{1+Y}
\end{equation}

I read similar posts on this forum but those are all different cases.

[$X,Y$ are independent exponentially distributed: What is the distribution of $X/(X+Y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416711/x-y-are-independent-exponentially-distributed-what-is-the-distribution-of-x)

Thanks for any suggestions.

[EDIT to add context]
Suppose to have two R.V., i.e. $Z$ and $T$, given by
\begin{equation}
Z = \frac{X}{1+Y},
\end{equation}
 and 
\begin{equation}
T = \frac{U}{1+V}
\end{equation}

I have to calculate the following probability:
\begin{equation}
P_x = P[Z>K(1+T)-1].
\end{equation}

Now, p(Z) and p(T) are the pdfs respectively of Z and T, given by (differentiating respect to T)

\begin{equation}
p(Z) = \frac{\lambda_1 \lambda_2 e^{\frac{-Z}{\lambda2}}}{(\lambda_2+\lambda_1 Z)^2} +  \frac{e^{\frac{-Z}{\lambda2}}}{(\lambda_2+\lambda_1 Z)},
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
p(T) = \frac{\lambda_3 \lambda_4 e^{\frac{-T}{\lambda4}}}{(\lambda_4+\lambda_3 T)^2} +  \frac{e^{\frac{-T}{\lambda4}}}{(\lambda_4+\lambda_3 T)}.
\end{equation}

Finally the probability that I'm looking for is given by

\begin{equation}
p_x = P[Z>K(1+T)-1] = \int_{0}^{\infty}p(T)\int_{K(1+T)-1}^{\infty} p(Z) dZdT
\end{equation}

[Why I asked]

I asked the pdf of $Z$ when $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. and exponentially distributed (same for $T$), because it seems that the two integrals in p_x don't converge to a solution for $Z>0$ and $T>0$.

How can I solve $p_x$?

That is the context.

Thanks again.

[QUESTION ON PROBABILITY MOVED TO SPECIFIC QUESTION]

[Probability calculation when the R.V. are the ratio of variables i.i.d. and exponentially distributed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193512/probability-calculation-when-the-r-v-are-the-ratio-of-variables-i-i-d-and-expo)

Answer (score 5):

We need to find $P(\frac{X}{1+Y} \leq z)$ for some $z \geq 0$. This resolves to $P(X \leq z(1+Y))$. So now we can set up our integration limits:

$$
\begin{align*}
&\int_{y=0}^{\infty} \int_{x=0}^{z(1+y)} \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 y} \lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 x} \, dx \, dy \\
&=\lambda_1\lambda_2 \int_{y=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda_1 y}\left(-\frac{1}{\lambda_2} \right) \left. e^{-\lambda_2 x} \right|_{x=0}^{x=z(1+y)} \, dy\\
&=-\lambda_1 \int_{y=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda_1 y} (e^{-\lambda_2 z(1+y)}-1) \, dy \\
&=-\lambda_1 \int_{y=0}^\infty e^{-y(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)-\lambda_2z}-e^{-\lambda_1 y} \, dy \\
&\dots \\
&=1-\frac{\lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_1 z}}{\lambda_2+\lambda_1 z}.
\end{align*}
$$

Now differentiate w.r.t. $z$ and you can retrieve your pdf.

[Edited to generalize for two exponential with different rates.]

Comment: The answer could be more general if the parameters of $X$ and $Y$ where different. (+1)

Comment: The question specifically stated X and Y are i.i.d.

Comment: OP says independent and exponentially distributed. It does not say independent and exponentially distributed with the same parameters, hence though they are both exp distributed they can have different param's :-). Identically distributed  is when we have the same pdf for both.

Comment: Oops, you are correct. I've modified the answer accordingly.